# How do I create a generic function which converts json string into a struct in golang?

Tags: json, function, go, interface

First of all, I have the folowing struct:

```
type User struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    FullName string
    Mail string
}
```

And I have tried to create the folowing function:

```
func FromJson(emptyJsonAble interface{},jsonString string) interface{} {
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &emptyJsonAble)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return emptyJsonAble
}
```

I have called to the function in the folowing way:

```
user := FromJson(User{}, str)
```

But the function returns the folowing map instead of User struct:

**map[FullName:a Mail:a Password:b Username:a]**

How do I return the struct itself **(witout converting the returned object every time)**?

In other words, how to make the function to consider emptyJsonAble as User type when give.
I have tryed to work with reflect.Type, but I'm stuck

Comment: `json.Unmarshal` already is a function to do that, and it works the only reasonable way - by taking a pointer to the value to deserialize into. What are you trying to change about that behavior with your wrapper function?

Comment: Because I want to save repeating those lines of code including casting jsonString into byte arrayy

Comment: So remove the return value and return statement and use it the same way you'd use `json.Unmarshal`.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the User struct through, you are effectively passing it a copy of the value, in your scenario what you want to do is pass a pointer reference to the type. Then, because you already have a pointer, you do not need to pass by reference inside of your function:

`user := FromJson(&User{}, str)`

`err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), emptyJsonAble)`

https://play.golang.org/p/uXMcFCl138y

UPDATE:

equally, because you are now passing by reference, you do not need to return a copy of the unmarshalled data struct:

https://play.golang.org/p/GJKqVJLbRCZ

In both cases, we can see the results are the same, so your return of the data is unnecessary

Comment: Thank you very mcuh!
I changed the function to return error instead of interface because it's already create the object inside emptyJsonAble pointer